# How to make my call as private to others?

Tags: java, android, telephonymanager, core-telephony

In android how to make a private calls that is how to hide the caller I'd to the other people for keep my number as more secured. I try this by using ITelephony class, but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Handling and making private calls is not on our hand. Even this feature we can not implement as its services are provided by the Telephone companies and totally handled by service providers. So you can not implement the feature. You need to ask to the service providers to get this feature in your cell phone but you can not implement.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can not. As far as I know your carrier provider handles that request.